# tcpdf - HTML table showing up way too small

Tags: php, pdf

I'm using tcpdf (http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate PDFs of some tables and images.  The images are loaded without an issue, but I'm having issues with the writeHTML() function.

I can't seem to control the font sizes or table width/height through the HTML, so I end up with a tiny, tiny, tiny table that you have to print of and squint at to even attempt reading.

I've tried editing the table itself, CSS, even putting the table itself inside an h1, but nothing is changing the font size.  I have the font size in tcpdf set to 16, but this also has no affect.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: can you provide an example of the code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, anyways -- apparently tcpdf's HTML engine gives the  tag precedence over any CSS, or other size-adjusting tags.  After removing all of the  tags from the HTML and using pure CSS, everything cleared up.